# ElectronJS, JavaScript and Python - require is not defined tried all the options

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, python-3.x, electron

I have a problem when I try to execute the following line:

```
var path = require('path')
```

i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

all work fine except from require  error, why?

i have 3 files:

translate.js:

```
function get_translate(){
var path = require('path') 
var trans = document.getElementById("trans").value
document.getElementById("trans").value = ""

var options = {
scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/../engine/'),
args : [trans]
}
translate = PythonShell.run('translate_engine.py', options);
translate.on('message', function(message) {
swal(message);
})
}
```

translate.html:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="linkers/translate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<div class="container">
<button="btn btn-info"><a style="color:white" href="gui.html">Back</a> 
</button>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Translate App</h1>
  <br>
  <label>Enter you word here</label>
  <input id="trans" type="text" placeholder="Text"/>
  <button class="but but-success" onclick="get_translate()">Go</button>
</div>
</body>
```

translate_engine.py:

```
import sys
trans = sys.argv[1]
print(trans)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

thank's

Comment: `require('path')` is for NodeJS, not JS in the browser

Comment: ok, i understand but how i fix that? i only want to write text in form and click go and print the text to screen

Comment: You can't really "fix" that. You are using code for two completely different platforms mixed together. IF you want to use Node packages in the Browser, use something like browserify or webpack around it

Comment: ok, thank's. Can someone help me fix the code so I can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to execute this code in an electron BrowserWindow?

If yes, check if `nodeIntegration` isn't set to `false` when initiating the `BrowserWindow`.

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  minWidth: 370,
  minHeight: 520,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
  },
});
```

`nodeIntegration` is actually `true` by default, so you can remove this line as well – I'm just trying to make it super obvious ;)

As long as `nodeIntegration` is `true` you can run *any* nodeJS code in the electron render process.

This goes beyond your initial question and it's a little bit more advanced, but If you don't want to enable this as it comes with numerous [security issues](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md), you can just expose certain nodeJS methods to the render process. You can do this with a preload script.

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') // here you can re-expose certain methods such as `require`
  },
});
```

> preload String (optional) - Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page. This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node integration is turned on or off. The value should be the absolute file path to the script. When node integration is turned off, the preload script can reintroduce Node global symbols back to the global scope.

More infos can be found here:
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#event-loaded